# Symfony2: How to get user Object inside controller when using FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle to authenticate my users.

I'm trying to get the user object inside the Controller to register a trip where I should add the user object to this Trip before save.

I did not found how to do that because next method where I found it in symfony doc:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

renders the username as string, but I need the whole object.

Currently, I use this method, but it's not working properly.

```
$username = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$user = $em->getRepository('SiteUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur')->find($username);
```

How can I correctly do this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I think [Ramon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588852/ramon-kleiss) is right. You already have the user object.

Also in Symfony > 2.1.x you can use

```
$this->getUser();
```

inside the controller.

Answer (score 15):

The documentation for the `getUser` method indicates:

> either returns an object which implements __toString(), or a primitive string is returned.

And if we look in the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` class over [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php) (the base user class used by the FOSUserBundle) we can see that it does indeed have a `__toString` method:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return (string) $this->getUsername();
}
```

I think that you actually get the `User` object but because it implements a `__toString` method it can be rendered directly in templates.

In Twig you can use:

```
{{ dump(user) }}
```

To see what kind of object you have. But You are actually using an object, not a string.

Answer (score 9):

Solution:

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->container->get('security.context')
                    ->getToken()
                    ->getUser())
```

Comment: apparently it does exactly the same as a built-in method getUser()

Answer (score 3):

In FOSUser 1.3 you can't call directly `$this->getUser` in SecurityController.

You have to call `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();`

And this is enough to access the user object. 
No need to call `$user = $em->getRepository('SiteUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur')->find($username);`

Furthermore your `find` method automatically and implicitly cast your initial $username object to string because it doesn't wait an object as argument.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, to resolve it add the FOS classes in your use section i.e:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
```

Answer (score 2):

In symfony >= 3.2, [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html) states that:

> An alternative way to get the current user in a controller is to
>   type-hint the controller argument with [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface/UserInterface.html) (and default it
>   to null if being logged-in is optional):
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface\UserInterface;
>
> public function indexAction(UserInterface $user = null)
> {
>     // $user is null when not logged-in or anon.
> }
> ```
>
> This is only recommended for experienced developers who don't extend
>   from the [Symfony base controller](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller.html#the-base-controller-class-services) and don't use the [ControllerTrait](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.html)
>   either. Otherwise, it's recommended to keep using the getUser()
>   shortcut.

[Here is blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers) about it

Answer (score 0):

For FOSUser ^1.3 you can get current user from inside a controller that extends BaseController like this :

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function indexAction()
{
    /* @var $user \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface */
    if ($user = $this->getUser())
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($user);
        print_r($user->getRoles()); // method usage example

        exit;

        return $this->redirectToRoute('dashboard');
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
}
```