# Symfony 2.5 / FOSUserBundle Get user id in an EventListener

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i'm trying to get the user id in an event listener in Symfony 2.4 but as far as I know EventListener isn't called by a controller so i can't user the

$this->getUser();

What is the best way to get the id?

I thought about giving it in services.yml that calls the event.

Thanks for anyhelp or any documentation that would help.

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In a controller** you should be able [since symfony 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15237105/3625883) to simple use

```
 $user = $this->getUser();
 $userId = $user->getId();
```

Or you can get the current logged in user object from security context

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$userId = $user->getId();
```

Or using the [FOSUserBundle service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17003884/3625883) (apparently it is an alternative of the built-in method getUser(), as the comment in the linked page said )

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());
$userId = $user->getId();
```

---

**Update**

If you are **in a event listener** you need to inject the container via Dependency Injection into your listener class in order to acccess it. Give a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17022330/3625883

---

**Second update**

The previous links do exactly what you asked but I want only to notice a thing: in general is not a good practise to inject the  entire service container, you should inject only the security.context . For more information : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15922525/3625883

Comment: I already tried it
first method :
Attempted to call method "getUser" on class ...
second method :
Notice: Undefined property: XXXXX::$container

Comment: Are you calling it in a controller?

Comment: No, as i mentioned, i'm in an Event in the EventListener folder

Comment: thanks, i think that it will work ! i can't say that the answer is usefull because i've no notoriety but thanks :)

Comment: I added a notice about the service container injection.

Comment: Do you know how to put the argument ? 
it should be as this :
 <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
but integrating this service_container but it doesn't work ( i must have the wrong integration ^^ )

Comment: If you have any problem with service definition you should give a look at the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

Answer (score -2):

```
$user_id=$this->getUser()->getId();
```