# Getting the ROLES of the user after logging in with FOSUserBundle Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am having a problem on getting roles of a user that has logged in. I tried to override the SecurityController and have the following code :

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $userId = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
    $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('id'=>$userId));

    if( $user->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') && $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') ){
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('adminpage'));
    }

    if($user->hasRole('ROLE_ACCOUNTING') && $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') ){
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('accountingpage'));
    }
....
```

The problem here is that getId() throws an error like so:

> Error: Call to a member function getId() on string

I tried another approach with the following code like so:

```
if($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')  && $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') ){
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('adminpage'));
    }

    if($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ACCOUNTING')  && $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') ){
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('accountingpage'));
    }
```

But it always evaluates to ROLE_ADMIN even I logged in a user with ROLE_ACCOUNTING thus giving me a Access Denied message.

How can I fix this?

Thank you very much!

PS. I used Symfony 2.7

Comment: what version of symfony?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$userId = $user->getId();
```

or

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$userId = $user->getId();
```

or, using FOSUserBundle

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->container
          ->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());
$userId = $user->getId();
```

Then do the role check.

The error you get, where you get a string instead of an object, is because the base User class has a `__toString()` method where it returns the username.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12663880/5043552 for a similar question.

Also your first check, using `->hasRole()` is not recommended, see below an excerpt from the User Model of `FOSUserBundle`

```
/**
 * Never use this to check if this user has access to anything!
 *
 * Use the SecurityContext, or an implementation of AccessDecisionManager
 * instead, e.g.
 *
 *         $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER');
 *
 */
public function hasRole($role)
```

Your second role check should work just fine.